# Sling servlet request method property ignored?

Tags: java, aem, sling

Perhaps I've misunderstood what the annotations are for in a Sling servlet or what they control.

I have a servlet defined with the following:

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = false, label = "File Processor Servlet")
@Service(serviceFactory = false, value = javax.servlet.Servlet.class)
@Properties(value = {
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "GET" }),
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value = { "json" }),
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = { "/bin/FileProcessor" })
```

Now this can be deployed and works fine (I'm using a CQ5.3 environment btw), which is good and everyone is happy.

However it was only when I was taking someone through my code that I realised I'd implemented the `doDelete()` method which also works fine, **but** as you can see, I have not declared it as a method in the `sling.servlet.methods` property in the annotations.

I had assumed that the omission of DELETE as a method in the annotations would have caused problems and the servlet would be blocked from handling it.

Have I missed the point of these annotations?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sling.servlet.resourceTypes`, `sling.servlet.selectors`, `sling.servlet.extensions` and the `sling.servlet.methods` values are valid only if the **sling.servlet.paths** property is not set. If the paths property is set then all the others are ignored.

Quoting from the sling docs.

**sling.servlet.methods** - The request methods supported by the servlet. The property value must either be a single String, an array of Strings or a Vector of Strings. *This property is ignored if the sling.servlet.paths property is set*. If this property is missing, the value defaults to GET, regardless of which methods are actually implemented/handled by the servlet.

Refer the [Sling Engine Documentation](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) for more info.

**Edit** Including @BertrandDelacretaz comments:

And BTW registering servlets on paths is not recommended in Sling, quoting the same docs "Creating a resource at the desired path, with a resource type that maps to a servlet, provides the same result in most cases while taking advantage of more Sling built-in features". Features like access control for example.

Comment: And as you can see in the linked documentation you can use the special annotation for servlets instead of the "Service" and "Properties": "SlingServlet".

Comment: @Thomas - Yes. But either way, the rules applicable are the same. :)

Comment: And BTW registering servlets on paths is not recommended in Sling, quoting the same docs "Creating a resource at the desired path, with a resource type that maps to a servlet, provides the same result in most cases while taking advantage of more Sling built-in features". Features like access control for example.